# #!/bin/ksh not working in redhat linux

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I am using the command:

```
#!/bin/ksh
```

as the first line in my shell script (hopefully this will dictate the shell to execute in the KSH Shell) . But when i am executing my shell like below it is not actually happening.

```
sh test_shell.txt
```

But when i using like below with or with out (#!/bin/ksh) i am getting proper output.

```
ksh test_shell.txt
```

In my code i am setting a value to variable like below.

```
set -A variable_name
```

But i think -A is not recognized in sh where as it is working as an assignment in ksh shell.
How can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you verify the *path* to `ksh`?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention i am doing the above in REDHAT LIUNX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you execute

```
sh test_shell.txt
```

then you are launching the `sh` (Bourne) shell with your file name as the script to run. In this case the first line of the script is ignored because it is a comment. The rest of the script is expected to be in Bourne shell syntax, because that's the shell you requested.

If you set your script to executable (`chmod +x test_shell.txt`) and then run it with:

```
./test_shell.txt
```

then the kernel will read the first line of the script, see it starts with the special `#!`, and run your script with `/bin/ksh`.

Comment: Yes it is working for me , May i please know if there is any alternative approach for this.